# How to skip currently processing file from Mapper in MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a MapReduce program that reads files recursively from a folder and its sub folders. I have written a custom file input format class to make isSplitable is false to ensure one full file goes to only one mapper and it reads file line by line. Now that I am searching for a pattern and if a match is found I don't want to continue and want to skip the execution of current file. How can we achieve that in a mapper class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply re-implement the run method. For example like this, with a boolean field to short-circuit into the cleanup phase directly.

```
public class SkipMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

  private boolean skip;

  @Override
  protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
      Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>.Context context)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    // map with the matcher
    if (match) {
      skip = true;
    }

  }

  @Override
  public void run(Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>.Context context)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    setup(context);
    try {
      while (!skip && context.nextKeyValue()) {
        map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
      }
    } finally {
      cleanup(context);
    }
  }

}
```